# Creation of a windows installer package

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installshield, advanced-installer

Can Visual Studio make a Windows installer from a c++ project (MSI or EXE setup file) without relying on InstallShield or Advanced Installer?

Actually, I haven't found the way to create an installation package with Visual Studio, as I did for InstallShield or Advanced Installer!

Comment: @nvoigt please see the edits for "the" proper question. If it's still not proper for you, please let me know.

Comment: In my cmake based builds on windows I have cmake generate nsis installers for me. Although recently cmake has added the ability to use wix to generate installers as well. Although I agree replacing your project files with cmake ones for this ability only is an overkill.

Comment: @drescherjm I haven't worked before with cmake (limited use). What about Visual Studio? Have you tried it?

Comment: CMake generates visual studio project files. However again this is an overkill if all you need is an installer.

Comment: @drescherjm
I am having loads of dll to load with my solution. And I would like to make the installer to not put them everytime.

Comment: I would edit your question to put this added information.

Comment: @drescherjm yes go for it.

Comment: I meant for you to do this. I need to get back to the day job at the moment.. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you can. It is called deploying your Project.
Visit the link to see the steps involved

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384837.aspx
```

Comment: the problem is that this one is using InstallShield Limited Edition Project, which is not provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: Both ISLE and Advanced Installer have free VS extensions, to create setup projects, with limited access to their features. You can install ISLE from here (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f25e8e90-42e3-47b2-b61c-a6fa2ae9b3dc). The Advanced Installer VS extension is automatically installed when you install Advanced Installer on your machine, and VS is already present on that machine.